# Using ReportViewer 9 control in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reportviewer, reportingservices-2005

I am writing an ASP.NET app that uses a SQL Server 2005 with SSRS setup.  I want to use the ReportViewer control but I get an error when using ReportViewer 10 because it needs SSRS 2008.

How can I use ReportViewer 9 within my application.  I've added a reference to the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll version 9 and removed the reference to version 10.

My markup is as follows:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
<!-- standard markup -->
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

but when I try to run this I get the following error:

> CS0433: The type
>   'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer'
>   exists in both
>   'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll'
>   and
>   'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll'

What have I missed!?

**Update:**
When trying to use the ReportViewer 10 I get the following error:

> "Remote report processing requires
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting
>   Services or later."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured it out, forgot to change 3 references in the web.config file:

within HttpHandler:

```
<add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

and within assemblies:

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
```

Comment: I found that you will also need to run your app in Classic mode (app pool setting) for ReportViewer 9.0 to work.

Answer (score 2):

don't know why, but you should try if this works:
add the following code to web.config

```
  <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

before

```
</configuration>
```

it worked for me